Spring-batch - read and write in the same table in batches (pagination)
How can I use (or is there a way) to use spring-batch to read and write in the same table in batches?
For context: I have a table that has millions of registers. From time to time many of those registers have to be reprocessed because of a given stimulus.
My train of thought was to get from the table in batches since there are so many registers (using pagination, which is the current case). For each item, validate if it needs to be updated, if it does, update it, if not just let it be.
Also, simultaneously to the spring-batch execution, new registers could be arriving to the table, and as they would be happening after the stimulus that triggered the spring-batch execution, they would not need to be reprocessed.
I thought about using an updated_time on the table, and just fetch registers from a previous time than what caused the reprocessing stimulus, since everything arriving on the table after the stimulus would not need to be reprocessed.
The thing is, if I use the updated_time and fetch in batches using pagination, and then update one of those registers, the register updated will have a new update_time that comes from after the stimulus, and so it could mess my pagination, leading to inconsistency and not processing all of the itens that should be reprocessed.
Does anyone has an idea on how can I handle this?

Don't it will lead to surprising result (processing half of the records) use a cursor for reading instead.

+1 to what @M.Deinum said. Use a cursor based reader and it should work, here is an example: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-samples/src/main/resources/org/springframework/batch/samples/jdbc/job/jdbcCursor.xml
